# Validation Rule on picklist under opportunities

Tags: opportunity, picklist, validation-rule

There are 2 requirements:

1. standard users can’t update the status of a record beyond “open won” (so that only SF Admins or auto processes update “registered” and the stages beyond registration. Validation rule for this:

~

```
 AND( 

    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
    ISCHANGED(StageName),

    OR(TEXT(StageName) = "Registered",
    TEXT(StageName) = "Pre-Certified",
    TEXT(StageName) = "Documentation, Submission",
    TEXT(StageName) = "Performance verified",
    TEXT(StageName) = "Appeals",
    TEXT(StageName) = "Certification/ Closed Won")

    )
```

Requirement 2: Standard users cannot update the status of a record that is already Registered (or post-registered phase). For us, some Opp was already “Registered” but some standard user  was able to change the record to “Open Won.”

I am looking for the validation rule of requirement 2 and which should align with first requirement also.

Thanks, Please guide.

Comment: have you incorporated all the conditions in your validation rule?

Comment: you requirements in the first 2 paragraphs are different, and also Validation Rule (VR) you have in the question can't prevent 'Registered' stage selection as you state in the last paragraph - are there any other VR or requirements (you have 'Appeals' value validation in your VR) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 validation rules.

> Under opportunities there is a picklist called STAGE, the standard users (anyone other than Salesforce admin) should not be able to select and save the values in the picklist after the value : "registered"

Ans: You need to mention which particular stageNames standard users will not be allowed to select.

Rule will be like this (put all the stageNames with || condition) and show the error message when following is true:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(StageName), 
    (TEXT(StageName) == 'Registered' || TEXT(StageName) == 'Closed Won'), 
    $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator'
)
```

> When new opportunity is being created, in first place only it does not allow to select the value "Registered" in the Stage picklist.

Ans: Show the error message when following is true.

```
ISNEW() && (TEXT(StageName) == 'Registered')
```

> Standard users cannot update the status of a record that is already Registered (or post-registered phase). For us, some Opp was already “Registered” but some standard user was able to change the record to “Open Won.”

Ans: You need to check `PRIORVALUE(field)` in the `OR` condition

```
AND( 

$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
ISCHANGED(StageName), 
OR(
PRIORVALUE(StageName) = "Registered",
TEXT(StageName) = "Registered",
TEXT(StageName) = "Pre-Certified",
TEXT(StageName) = "Documentation, Submission",
TEXT(StageName) = "Performance verified",
TEXT(StageName) = "Appeals",
TEXT(StageName) = "Certification/ Closed Won")

)
```

Comment: two requirements: 1. standard users can’t update the status of a record beyond “open won” (so that only SF Admins or auto processes update “registered” and the stages beyond registration. for this the VR is AND( 

$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
ISCHANGED(StageName),

OR(TEXT(StageName) = "Registered",
TEXT(StageName) = "Pre-Certified",
TEXT(StageName) = "Documentation, Submission",
TEXT(StageName) = "Performance verified",
TEXT(StageName) = "Appeals",
TEXT(StageName) = "Certification/ Closed Won")

)

Comment: I have updated the question , please check and guide, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: requirement 2: Standard users cannot update the status of a record that is already Registered (or post-registered phase).  Example:  this Opp was already “Registered” but some standard user  was able to change the record to “Open Won.”   Need validation rule for requirement 2 and should align with the VR of requirement 1

Comment: Done, URL to new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174799/validation-rule-standard-users-cannot-update-the-status-of-a-record-beyond-one

Comment: @SantanuBoral It was 2 requirements in the original question, you just decided to skip some of them: *You need to mention which particular stageNames standard users will not be allowed to select.* isn't an answer

Comment: @SantanuBoral wording is off, but overall requirements are the same - actually it seems like he wants the user to be able to set Stage to 'Registered', so my answer has to be tweaked.

Comment: @SamreenAdil see my updated answer for requirement 2, though I have not compiled but that should be the logic

Answer (score 0):

Formula below won't let any user beside System Administrator to set Stage value to any from this list ('Registered' , 'Pre-Certified' , 'Documentation, Submission' , 'Performance verified' , 'Appeals' , 'Certification/ Closed Won') and also to change it when it's set already to any from the list:

```
AND( 
 $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
 OR(
  ISCHANGED(StageName),
  ISNEW()
 ),
 OR(
  CONTAINS("Registered:Pre-Certified:Documentation, Submission:Performance verified:Appeals:Certification/ Closed Won", TEXT(StageName)), 
  CONTAINS("Registered:Pre-Certified:Documentation, Submission:Performance verified:Appeals:Certification/ Closed Won", TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName))) 
 )
)
```

The only downside of it is that any of your other Stages shouldn't have a value that is a part of this validated string - e.g.'Submission' - in this case you have to use CASE instead of CONTAINS:

```
CASE( PRIORVALUE(StageName),
 'Registered', 1,
 'Pre-Certified', 1,
 'Documentation, Submission', 1,
 'Performance verified', 1,
 'Appeals', 1,
 'Certification/ Closed Won', 1,
0) = 1
```