# Validation rule : Standard users cannot update the status of a record beyond one specific value in picklist

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

Requirement : Standard users cannot update the status of a record that is already Registered (or post-registered phase). Example: Opp was already “Registered” but some standard user was able to change the record to “Open Won.” Need validation rule for this.

Note: "Stage" is a picklist under opportunity

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VLOOKUP (requires a custom object loaded with each stage name and a value):

```
VLOOKUP($ObjectType.Stages__c.Fields.Ordinal_Value__c,
        $ObjectType.Stages__c.Fields.Name,
        TEXT(StageName)) <
VLOOKUP($ObjectType.Stages__c.Fields.Ordinal_Value__c,
        $ObjectType.Stages__c.Fields.Name,
        TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName)))
```

Other solutions are also possible, but may require more complicated formulas. You can look up the TEXT, PRIORVALUE, and VLOOKUP functions [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US).